# how to get the values correctly from the input tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How would I get input tag values in the follow situation?

I'm having a problem selecting the correct value from the input, currently I'm only getting the first value = text_1, and I do not know why I'm not picking up the others ...

this is a prototype to select values in a panel, in which the user tries to use the mouse to select which is the most interesting for him.

**I only want the one value clicked after the button**

Can someone help me?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#openButton").click(function(){
        alert("Value: " + $("div > :submit").val());
        });
    });
```

```css
.item {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.flex {
    flex: 0;
}

.imagem-chave{
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;        
}

.container-grande_img{

    border-top: 2px solid #0000FF;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0000FF;
    border-left: 2px solid #0000FF;
    border-right: 2px solid #0000FF;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
}
.botao{
    margin-top:-30px;
}

.legend {
    width: 60px;
    font-size:14px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color:#00004d;
}

.label {
    display: inline;
    padding: .2em .6em .3em;
    font-size: 50%;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border-radius: .25em;
}

div.inputbutton {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;

}

div.inputbutton input {
background: url('/img/livre.png') no-repeat;
cursor: pointer;
width: 100px;
height: 130px;
border: none;
background-size: 100%;
}

span.text {
position: absolute;
bottom: 10%;
left: 5px;
width: 100%;
font-size: 15px;
color: white;
}
#myNavbar{
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <div class="item flex imagem-chave">
                        <div class="inputbutton">
                        <span class="text">TEXT_1</span>
                            <input type="submit" class="btTxt submit" value="TEXT_1"  id="TEXT_1">
                        </div>                        
                        <div class="inputbutton">
                        <span class="text">TEXT_2</span>
                            <input type="submit" class="btTxt submit" value="TEXT_2"  id="TEXT_2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="inputbutton">
                        <span class="text">TEXT_3</span>
                            <input type="submit" class="btTxt submit" value="TEXT_3"  id="TEXT_3">
                        </div>
                        <div class="inputbutton">
                        <span class="text">TEXT_4</span>
                            <input type="submit" class="btTxt submit" value="TEXT_4"  id="TEXT_4">
                        </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="item flex botao ">
                    <button type="Liberar" id="openButton" class="btn btn-primary" >open key</button>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var lastClicked = null;
 $('.btTxt').click(function(event) {
          lastClicked = event.target
    });

 $("#openButton").click(function(){
    alert("Value: " + $(lastClicked).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was misreading the question. If you're going to use multiple buttons to select an option, you should be using radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="some_option" value="TEXT_1" id="option_TEXT_1" />
<label for="option_TEXT_1">TEXT_1</label>
<input type="radio" name="some_option" value="TEXT_2" id="option_TEXT_2" />
<label for="option_TEXT_2">TEXT_2</label>
<input type="radio" name="some_option" value="TEXT_3" id="option_TEXT_3" />
<label for="option_TEXT_3">TEXT_3</label>
<input type="radio" name="some_option" value="TEXT_4" id="option_TEXT_4" />
<label for="option_TEXT_4">TEXT_4</label>
<button type="Liberar" id="openButton" class="btn btn-primary" >open key</button>
```

In the JS:

```
$("#openButton").click(function () {
    alert(document.querySelector(
            'input[name="some_option"]:checked').value);
}
```

If you really want to use buttons, `<input type=submit>` elements are not the best tool for this because the user might be clicking a bunch of them on the same page:

```
<button class="some_option" id="option_TEXT_1">TEXT_1</button>
<button class="some_option" id="option_TEXT_2">TEXT_2</button>
<button class="some_option" id="option_TEXT_3">TEXT_3</button>
<button class="some_option" id="option_TEXT_4">TEXT_4</button>
<button type="Liberar" id="openButton" class="btn btn-primary" >open key</button>
```

And in the JS:

```
var option = "";
$("button.some_option").click(function () {
    option = $(this).attr("id");
}

$("#openButton").click(function () {
    alert(option);
}
```

---

Original answer, where I thought you were asking for some text:

According to [the documentation for `val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/), it only gets the value from the first element (if you call it on a set of multiple elements).

Consider using [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) with a callback.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#openButton").click(function() {
    $('input[type="submit"]').each(function() {
      alert("Value: " + $(this).val());
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h5,
p,
ul,
li,
a {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  font-family: "Nunito", Helvetica, Arial;
  color: #222222;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu-bg {
  background: #00004d;
}

.menu {
  max-width: 2000px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 250px
}

.menu a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.menu-logo a {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 10px;
  float: left;
}

.menu-logo img {
  padding-left: 0px;
  width: 159px;
  height: 24px;
}

.column {
  min-height: 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-start {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: normal;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.center {
  justify-content: center;
}

.container-grande {
  max-width: 1000px;
  max-height: 600px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  display: flex;
  border: 0px solid #ccc;
  padding: 00px 00px 500px 00px;
  background: #F5F5F5;
}

.container-grande item {
  max-width: 420px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container-grande h1 {
  border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
  flex: 1 1 400px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.container-cor {
  width: 97%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.flex {
  flex: 0;
}

.imagem-chave {
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.container-grande_img {
  border-top: 2px solid #0000FF;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0000FF;
  border-left: 2px solid #0000FF;
  border-right: 2px solid #0000FF;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.botao {
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.legend {
  width: 60px;
  font-size: 14px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #00004d;
}

.label {
  display: inline;
  padding: .2em .6em .3em;
  font-size: 50%;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: .25em;
}

div.inputbutton {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.inputbutton input {
  background: url('/img/livre.png') no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 130px;
  border: none;
  background-size: 100%;
}

span.text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
}

#myNavbar {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
  background: white;
  margin-right: -50px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.navbar-header .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background: black;
}

.menu-nav ul li a:hover {
  background: transparent;
  color: grey;
}

.menu-nav ul li a:active {
  background: transparent;
  color: grey;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #00004d;
  border-color: #00004d;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ecdbff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #ecdbff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #ecdbff;
  background-color: #00004d;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
  color: #ecdbff;
  background-color: #00004d;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #00004d;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #00004d;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #ecf0f1;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #ecdbff;
}

.tam {
  height: 50%;
  width: 1200px;
  background-color: powderblue;
  margin: auto;
}

.tam_Cadastro {
  width: 1200px;
  background-color: powderblue;
  margin: auto;
}

.gerarPDF {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 825px) {
  .navbar-header {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-left,
  .navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .collapse.in {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item flex imagem-chave">
  <div class="inputbutton">
    <span class="text">Text_1</span>
    <input type="submit" class="btTxt submit" value="Text_1" id="Text_1">
  </div>
  <div class="inputbutton">
    <span class="text">Text_2</span>
    <input type="submit" class="btTxt submit" value="Text_2" id="Text_2">
  </div>
  <div class="inputbutton">
    <span class="text">Text_3</span>
    <input type="submit" class="btTxt submit" value="Text_3" id="Text_3">
  </div>
  <div class="inputbutton">
    <span class="text">Text_4</span>
    <input type="submit" class="btTxt submit" value="Text_4" id="Text_4">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item flex botao ">
  <button type="Liberar" id="openButton" class="btn btn-primary">Open Key</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @theFlash Can you please update your question with more details on what you mean by that?  As you can see by most of the answers, we are reading your question as asking how to get all the values.